# Cargar automáticamente un campo en un modelo de django

Tags: python, django

estoy haciendo un modelo en django y quiero que el campo **date** se cargue automáticamente con la fecha en la que se guardo el mismo sin que el usuario lo tenga que hacer manualmente, como lo puedo hacer??

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class ChickenPrice(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    egg_price = models.IntegerField()
    birth_rate = models.IntegerField()
    shed_cost = models.IntegerField()
    vaccine_cost = models.IntegerField()
    chicken_price = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo de 2 formas:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

o por otra parte

```
date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

o tambien:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)
```

referencia desde la documentacion:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now